# ORA-06152 character string buffer too small in simple select query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I was hired by this company to develop a system.. Among other things, this system is supposed to read data from an Oracle database.
I was given access to a view inside this database and I read the data from this view using a query similar to this one:

```
select * from (
    select status, TO_CHAR(inservicedate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS inservicedate, userlogin, loc_code, remarks, 
    TO_CHAR(lastactivity, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS lastactivity, ROWNUM AS rnum from MY_USER.THE_VIEW 
    WHERE city = 'Guadalajara' AND ROWNUM <= 1000 order by rnum
) where rnum > 0
```

A few remarks on this query:

- I use the `ROWNUM <= X` and `rnum > Y` to get chunks of data.
- The `Remarks` column contains a string that in some rows is huge (over 2000 chars long).
- The dates are formatted to 'dd/mm/yyyy' to parse them to a C# obj.

The application has been using this query to read data from months without having any problems until early this week. When I use the Oracle SQL Developer to run the query I get the error:

> ORA-06152 character string buffer too small in line 1

I've been trying to find an answer to this but every SO question I find is about creating procedures or things actually more complicated that the query I am trying to execute.

I have tried many things to discover what the problem is and I noticed that if I comment out `remarks` (meaning I don't include it on the query) It works just fine but I also noticed that if I perform the same search but selecting **only** the `remarks` it works fine as well, so... That is confusing.

Other thing that I tried was removing the date formatting but the same error was found.

Any idea on what the problem is or how I can begin to identify it is very welcomed.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the view call a function, perhaps to generate `remarks`? Your 'chunking' is a bit odd, you'll get an indeterminate set of rows, which may explain why it doesn't seem to error consistently.

Comment: What's the data type of `remarks`? Also, it looks like you're selecting from a view, not a table. Is that view doing any sort of processing on `remarks`?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently getting rows in, I think, an indeterminate order. Your `order by rnum` orders the rows *after* they've been selected, so you're not guaranteed to get "pages" of results here. Try reformulating your query like this:

```
select * from ( 
    select q1.*, rownum as rnum from (
        select status, TO_CHAR(inservicedate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS inservicedate, 
               userlogin, loc_code, remarks, 
               TO_CHAR(lastactivity, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS lastactivity
          from MY_USER.THE_VIEW 
         WHERE city = 'Guadalajara' 
         order by userlogin, loc_code
        ) q1
    where ROWNUM <= 1000
) where rnum > 0
```

This has nothing to do with your error, by the way. I'm pretty sure that's a PL/SQL error, not a SQL error.

Comment: Thank you for this, I modified my query to adapt it to this syntax but I got an error: 12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"